# macOS pdflatex : TEXINPUTS default value for streaming in STDIN

Tags: mac, texinputs

I have a very simple file `hello.tex`

I want to use streaming instead of taking file as argument, and the following commands actually **work**:

`cat hello.tex | pdflatex`

`cat hello.tex | TEXINPUTS= pdflatex`

When `TEXINPUTS` is not defined `pdflatex` seems to use a default value.

---

### My problem

I want to load some custom LaTeX environments and when I set `TEXINPUTS`:

`cat hello.tex | TEXINPUTS="./" pdflatex`

I get an error as it can not load default LaTeX files:

`LaTeX Error: File 'article.cls' not found.`

---

Is there a way to add some custom paths to `TEXINPUTS` without unsetting default paths, and to continue **streaming in stdin**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the value of TEXINPUTS starts or ends with `:` then the standard search path is used before or after the directories specified in the environment variable, so to add a directory `local` before the default path use `TEXINPUTS=local:`

Comment: I was hoping to be able to include file with relative path in parent folders like `../../common/instructions.tex` but it does not seem possible just by adding the current working directory to `TEXINPUTS`. Is there another way to tell `pdflatex` how to resolve relative paths?

Comment: @kube There is never any need to add the current directory as that is searched before the path, and relative paths are resolved against each directory in the path by default. So you should not need to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so after a little search (in fact it was a long search, but found the answer 5 minutes after posting the question):

`:FIGURES//` seems to be the default path I was looking for.

And now this command is working:

`cat hello.tex | TEXINPUTS=":FIGURES//" pdflatex`

Comment: that makes it recursively look in all directories under FIGURES which will not help find `article.cls` (what does help is the leading `:` which means that FIGURES// is prepended to the default path.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you installed TeX Live using the MacTeX installer the default personal texmf tree has its root in ~/Library. You will have to initially create the tree texmf/tex/latex/ in ~/Library and place your personal files there. No need to reinvent the wheel.